# How to read from a file and search for the input of the user on the file? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

This my code i want to search for the input of the user i.e string on a certain .txt file and if it finds it displays date found else input not found.

```
Dim freader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strline, a As String
    freader = New IO.StreamReader(" C:\Users\neWbie889\Documents\vb\strings.txt")
    strline = freader.ReadLine
    Do While Not strline Is Nothing
        strline = freader.ReadLine()
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine("enter your string")
    a = Console.ReadLine()
    If strline = a Then
        Console.WriteLine("input found")
    ElseIf strline <> a Then
        Console.WriteLine("input not found")
    End If
    freader.Close()
```

the text file consists of data in this order:

750401 234523

456465 345345

054156 34534

023156 534543

156456 435345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all the text from the file into a string:

```
Dim allText As String = File.ReadAllText("path to file")
```

and then check for the string the user gave with [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
If allText.Contains(a) = True Then
    Console.WriteLine("input found")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("input not found")
End If
```

Comment: it says file not declared are you suggesting to use imports system.io sorry iam new and arent familiar with vb

Comment: @neWbie889 You can use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()` or `Imports System.IO` so you don't have to write `System.IO` all the time

Comment: okay that did solve the problem thank you for that but i couldnt use contains method as shown because bool is not higlighted by vb as shown in example.

Comment: @neWbie889 The example uses C#. C# has `bool` and VB has `Boolean`. What is the problem?

Comment: the program iam trying to create is:                                                                        
    'key in date by user 
    'search the text file For this Date 
    'found = yes then discount On this date or this is a discount date
    'if found = no then date not found

Comment: @neWbie889 I didn't write the whole code. I thought it was easy to understand. See edit

Comment: i solved it finally after struggling hopelessly for 4 days. thank you so much i can't appreciate enough for your help. yes,the contains method were in c# and i didn't see the reference and tried to use the same code but after you said it i realised it. thanks again i cant appreciate enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Imports System.IO
 Module Module1
 Sub Main()
    Dim a As String
    Dim allText As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\KronosXtitan\Documents\vb\ddates.txt")
    Console.WriteLine("enter a number")
    a = Console.ReadLine()
    If allText.Contains(a) = True Then
        Console.WriteLine("the number was found")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("the number was not found")
    End If


End Sub

End Module
```

thanks to γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε for helping me solve this